# Continue instruction of while loop not executed

Tags: java, while-loop, continue

A continue instruction in a while loop is not executed.
In Eclipse Debugging, the loop just breaks after the System.out.

Anyone know what may cause this, is there a way to debug on cpu instruction level to see what happens ?

```
  do { // recursive calls through element.parents() until the formula pattern (patternFormula) matches
                counter++;
                System.out.println(counter);
                lookupElement = lookupElement.parent();

                String s = replaceArrowTagAndClean(lookupElement.html()); // replace <img .. src=> and return text()

                m = patternFormula.matcher(s);
                if( (found = m.find()) ) {
                    oneMoreLookahead = false;
                    System.out.println("Continue " + counter);
                    continue;
                }
            } while(!found || oneMoreLookahead);

            System.out.println("End");
```

Output is:
1 
2
3
4
Continue 4
End

(Sry, had quite some trouble creating this post. lol)

Comment: please, show the code

Comment: Post code itself, not image of code. Do you expect us to rewrite it to test it out?

Comment: if found = m.find() true after the first iteration?

Comment: neither of your conditions in your while loop hold true at that point. Why should `continue;` change that?

Comment: What is your expected result? Why do you think it should behave that way?

Comment: I suggest to add the complete code to see if there is a problem on the logic. Don't copy and paste it as an image

Comment: I would initialize [found] before the loop, also what happens if there is an error in found = m.find()?  Might want to build some error handling in there.

Comment: Its jus a snippet, ofcourse found is defined. The expected result is 4 -> Continue 4 -> 5 -> End

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction `continue` will skip all the following lines of code in the loop and will go to the next iteration.

If you place the `continue` as the last line of code of the loop the behaviour leaving that instruction or removing it is the same.

In your case you can simply use the `break` instruction to exit the loop immediately.

Comment: I mistakenly thought the continue would jump to the start of the loop (behind the do { ) and skip the while condition: while(!found || oneMoreLookahead). That is not the case, thanks for help. (Clarification)